# How I can show Google Maps V2 into a AlertDialog android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I have created an android application in that I want to show Google Maps V2 into a AlertDialog.

My code is:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());

                View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt_mapview, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        BasicProfileSetup.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

                final AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();


                Button close = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.btnClose_promptMapView);

                // Some Code for initialize MAP

                close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        alertD.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertD.show();
```

prompt_mapview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClose_promptMapView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Close" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_promptMapView"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this code I gets the exception like:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post prompt_mapview code ?

Comment: use custom dialogbox. refere this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236247/how-to-create-alertdialog-programmatically-in-android/25236262#25236262

Comment: @yuvaツ. that code works for me.. thanks!!!

Comment: @yuvaツ but in that the MAP is display very dark. why this happens?

Comment: post code, xml & screen shot here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59084/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-yuva-).

Comment: Create a custom DialogFragment  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: having you found this solution??

Comment: Just refer this answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586665/mapview-in-a-dialog

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new activity that looks like alert dialog and put the map on it.

Comment: It does't satisfy users needs